# Getting Blank screen for QRCode scanner for the first time app installed in Android react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, react-qr-code

I am getting blank screen for QRCode scanner when the app is launcehed for the first time happening only on android devcies.
I am trying to scan QRcode in my app for this is have used react-native-qrcode-scanner.

Here is the package.json file details for the packages is used

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.3",
"react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
"react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
```

Hers is the code for accesing QRCode scanner

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Colors from '../../utility/Colors';
import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as booking from '../../store/action/booking';
import TextView from '../../components/UI/TextView';
import StringConstants from '../../utility/StringConstants';
import {Dimensions } from "react-native";
import normalize from '../../utility/ViewPortScaling';
import Images from '../../utility/Images';

const BarcodeReader = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [isBarcodeRead, setBarcode] = useState(false);

  const screenHeight = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);
  const onSuccess = e => {
    // console.log("inside success", e.data);
    dispatch(booking.isBarcodeRead(true, e.data));
    props.navigation.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{height:'100%', width: '100%', backgroundColor: Colors.toledo, paddingTop:30}}>
          <View style={{marginStart:20,flexDirection:'row',height:150}}>
                {/* back button */}
                <View style={{  height: 80, width: 50 }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={{height:80,width:50}}
                    onPress={() => {
                      props.navigation.goBack();
                    }}>
                    <Image style={{top:50, height:15,resizeMode: 'contain' }} source={Images.backArrow} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

              <View style={{flexDirection:'column',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',alignContent:'center',alignSelf:'auto'}}>
                    {/* company logo */}
                    <View style={{alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                      <Image style={{ height: 77 }} source={Images.logo} />
                    </View>
                  
                      <View style={{ alignItems:'flex-end',paddingTop:15 }}>
                        <TextView style={{fontSize: 14,fontFamily:'Montserrat-SemiBold',lineHeight:normalize(21)}}>{StringConstants.scanString}</TextView>
                      </View>
                </View>
              
          </View>
      <QRCodeScanner
        onRead={onSuccess}
        cameraStyle={{height: screenHeight}}
        reactivate={true}
        reactivateTimeout={20000}
        fadeIn={false}
      />
        <View style={{height:50,width:50,right:10,position:'absolute',alignSelf:'flex-end',flex:1,bottom:10}}>
            
          <TouchableOpacity style={{height:100,width:50}}

                        onPress={() => {
                              props.navigation.goBack();
                        }}>
          <Image style={{ width:50, height:50,resizeMode: 'contain' }} source={Images.closeWithBox} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
    </View>

  );

}
export default BarcodeReader;
```

Android device details
Vivo X60 Android version 13
Realme 5pro Android version 11

This same code was working fine QRCode Scanning worked properly but suddenly it started showing blank while using App for the first time.
Its working fine on restarting App sometimes it requires to restart the app 2-3 times

Answer (score -1):

You will need to install below, run the following commands:

```
1. npm install react-native-qrcode-scanner --save
2. npm install react-native-camera --save
3. npm install react-native-permissions --save
```

Please check the below configuration for android:

You need to add the "Vibration" permission to your AndroidManifest.xml of your project. This should be found in your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Add the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

You need to add the "missingDimensionStrategy" config for the 'react-native-camera' setting to 'general', this should be found in your android/app/build.gradle add the following:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' <-- insert this line
  }
}
```

Working code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Linking, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';


const App = () => {

  const onSuccess = e => {
    Linking.openURL(e.data).catch(err =>
      console.error('An error occured', err)
    );
  };

  return (
    <QRCodeScanner
      onRead={onSuccess}
      flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.torch}
      topContent={
        <Text style={styles.centerText}>
          Go to{' '}
          <Text style={styles.textBold}>wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code</Text> on
          your computer and scan the QR code.
        </Text>
      }
      bottomContent={
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonTouchable}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>OK. Got it!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      }
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centerText: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 18,
    padding: 32,
    color: '#777'
  },
  textBold: {
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#000'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 21,
    color: 'rgb(0,122,255)'
  },
  buttonTouchable: {
    padding: 16
  }
});

export default App;
```

versions of npm:

```
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Already added this permission  and I'm facing this issue on Android devices only

Comment: Check the edited answer as it's a working sample, Thank You!

Comment: react-native-qrcode-scanner uses "react-native-permissions": "^2.2.0" and we have installed "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0" so due to this getting issue while running build on android

Comment: nope, it will ask for permission for the first time and it will handle by react-native-permissions through react-native-qrcode-scanner

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it has something to do with the app permission to use the camera.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).